# Литералы с typeof "Undefined"

Tags: javascript

Какие литералы вернут true?

```
(typeof %литерал% == "undefined")
```

Comment: Я думаю, что все, определенные спецификацией языка, литералы, вернут false. Разве нет?

Comment: смысл в том, что есть универсальная ф-ция, которая имеет такой аргумент, который может быть известен, а может и нет
т.е. проверка на существование аргумента выглядит как typeof arg =="undefined". Если я хочу оставить его 'неопределенным', но за ним следуют еще аргументы, хочется ставить какую-то заглушку

Comment: пропустите этот аргумент совсем при вызове функции, а внутри проверяйте `arguments.length`

Comment: это очень громоздко, функция очень большая, а количество аргументов сильно варьируется. до этого проверял arg=="", но после недавних правок что-то пошло не так. Кажется, нашел решение в виде void()

Comment: @Igor, нет, вариант с undefined правильнее, т. к. именно так работают дефаултные значения в ES6.

Comment: Почему typeof "4px" - 2 ==NaN? Как такое возможно? А при typeof ("4px" - 2) == "number". (Это понятно, typeof NaN - number ).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел два решения проблемы

Банально но

```
typeof undefined == "undefined"
```

хотя тут никто не мешает задать эту переменную undefined и получается небезопасно

В итоге решение это void(0), т.к. попытка объявить функцию void вызовет ошибку

```
typeof void(0) == "undefined"
```

Хотя все равно получается какой-то зашквар :)

Comment: Глобальный `undefined` уже давно нельзя задать, а за своими переменными можно и самому последить. А `void` - это не функция, а унарный оператор.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что подразумевается под литералом. Если константа, то никакие.

Если что угодно, то `undefined` (это readonly-свойство, а не константа), любые необъявленные переменные (за исключением переменных в temporal dead zone в ES6), любые выражения, значениями которых является `undefined`.

Ну и ещё один магический случай - `document.all` :)

```js
console.log(typeof undefined == 'undefined')

console.log(typeof gdfsfjgsb == 'undefined')
console.log(typeof void 6789 == 'undefined')
console.log(typeof {}.jsdhfs == 'undefined')

console.log(typeof document.all == 'undefined')
console.log(document.all.length)
```

Comment: забавно :-) почему HTMLAllCollection имеет тип undefined?

Comment: @Grundy, по историческим причинам. Это была нестандартная фишка IE6, которая активно использовалась для проверки, что сайт открыли в IE6. А другим захотелось, чтобы у них и такие сайты работали, и другие не посылали с сообщением, что IE не поддерживается. Кстати не знаю, написано ли на этот счёт что-то в спецификации)